# How to access to the dataset transformed by automatic featurization steps in Azure Automated ML

Tags: azure, automl, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I’m performing a series of experiments with Azure AutoML and I need to see the featurized data. I mean, not just the new features names retrieved by method get_engineered_feature_names() or the featurization details retrieved by get_featurization_summary(), I refer to the whole transformed dataset, the one obtained after scaling/normalization/featurization that is therefore used to train the models.

Is it possible to access to this dataset or download it as a file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft expert confirmed that currently they "don't store the dataset from scaling/normalization/featurization after the run is complete". Answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/355323/how-to-access-to-the-featurized-dataset-in-automat.html).